# Как устроены, как работают и как самому сделать отменяемое событие?

Tags: c#, .net, события

Например, в WinForms есть много событий, где можно вызвать e.Cancel=true и тогда выполнение обработки события завершается.

Как оно устроеное, как работает и как самому реализовать такое событие?

Answer (score 3):

В .NET есть стандартный класс [`CancelEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Если вам нужно передать в обработчик какие-то данные - создаете наследник от `CancelEventArgs`. Если не нужно - просто используете `CancelEventArgs` как есть.

```
class MyEventArgs : CancelEventArgs
{

}

class SomeClass
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SomeEvent;

    private bool OnSomeEvent()
    {
        var args = new MyEventArgs();
        SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, args);

        return !args.Cancel;
    }

    public void SomeAction()
    {
        // наступило событие
        if (OnSomeEvent())
        {
            // продолжить
        }
        else
        {
            // отменить
        }
    }
}
```

Если вы используете свои параметры для события, то наследоваться от `CancelEventArgs` необязательно - можно просто добавить `bool Cancel` к уже существующим данным.

Answer (score 0):

1) (Необязательно) В некоторых случаях, если кто-то отменил присвоение, полезно выбросить исключение, оповестив таким образом присваювающий код о отмене, хотя можно обойтись и просто проверкой удачности присвоения, или вообще проигнорировать отмену. Класс исключения, который я использую.

```
[Serializable]
/// Исключение возникает при прерывании выполнения setter для свойства
public class SetterAbortException : Exception
{
    public SetterAbortException() { }
    public SetterAbortException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public SetterAbortException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
    protected SetterAbortException(
      System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
      System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    { }
}
```

2) Понадобится класс-потомок `EventArgs` содержащий флаг отмены и данные предлагаемые к присвоению. Если подходящего нет в .Net, подключенных библиотеках  или вашем решении, придётся создать.

```
public class ValueChangingEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ValueChangingEventArgs(decimal newvalue)
    {
        Cancel = false;
        NewValue = newvalue;
    }
    public bool Cancel { get; set; }
    public decimal NewValue { get; private set; }
}
```

3) Создаём EventHandler соответствующий нашему EventArgs.

```
public delegate void ValueChangingEventHandler(object sender, ValueChangingEventArgs ea);
```

4) Желательно реализовать закрытый/защищенный метод вызова события.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Вызов события о начале изменения значения
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">новое значение</param>
    /// <returns>Разрешение продолжить значение</returns>
    protected virtual bool onValueChanging(decimal value)
    {
        var ea = new ValueChangingEventArgs(value);
        if (ValueChanging != null)
        {
            ValueChanging(this, ea);
        }
        return !ea.Cancel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Событие возникает при начале изменения значения свойства Value
    /// </summary>
    public event ValueChangingEventHandler ValueChanging;
```

5) Осталось написать свойство с выбросом исключения при отмене или без него.

```
    private decimal value;
    /// <summary>
    /// Значение параметра в единицах СИ
    /// </summary>
    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set
        {
            if (!this.value.Equals(value)) //Проверяем новое значение присваивается или нет. Проверку можно убрать, если нужно, чтобы событие срабатывало даже, когда присваивается старое значение.
            {
                if (onValueChanging(value))
                {
                    this.value = value;                        
                    onValueChanged(); //Вызов события о завершении присвоения
                }
                else // Удалить если не нужно исключение
                    throw new SetterAbortException
                        ("Присвоение прервано");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 2) Уже есть `CancelEventArgs`

Comment: @andreycha, да и это отмечено в ответе PashaPash♦ .Однако там же написано "Если вы используете свои параметры для события, то наследоваться от CancelEventArgs необязательно". Событие,  обработчики которого, будут знать, что присваивается свойству, а не только факт попытки присвоения, может оказаться более полезным подписчикам...